# Tik-cd arrow length not the same across different frames

Tags: beamer, arrows, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

This is the code for the first frame

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile, t]{My slides}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
\text{The starting point}
\arrow{d} \\ 
\text{first node}  \arrow{r} &  \text{second node} \arrow{r} & \text{third node} 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which generates
[image]

Notice that the second horizontal arrow is slightly shorter than the first one. That's fine.

Now I add one more slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile, t]{My slides}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
\text{The starting point}
\arrow{d} \\ 
\text{first node}  \arrow{r} &  \text{second node} \arrow{r} & \text{third node} 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile, t]{My slides}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
\text{The starting point}
\arrow{d} \\ 
\text{first node}  \arrow{r} &  \text{second node} \arrow{r} & \text{third node}  \arrow{d} \\
& & \text{our destination} 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

All of a sudden, the length of the second horizontal arrow is now longer

[image]

Essentially causing a visual inconsistency.

How can I ensure that both horizontal arrows are of the same length? (Note that I don't need to display using two frames, I could display using one frame and use \only<1>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library for that: `overlay-beamer-styles`. Using it you can avoid duplication and the arrow length does not change. All you need to do is to add `visible on=<2>` for those elements that should only appear on slide 2.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile, t]{My slides}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
\text{The starting point}
\arrow{d} \\ 
\text{first node}  \arrow{r} &  \text{second node} \arrow{r} & \text{third node}  
\arrow[visible on=<2->]{d} \\
& & |[visible on=<2->]| \text{our destination} 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile, t]{My slides}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{tikzcd}
  \text{The starting point} \arrow{d} \\
  \text{first node} \arrow{r} & \text{second node} \arrow{r} & \text{third node} \only<2>{\arrow{d}} \\
  &&%
  \only<1>{\text{\color{white}our destination}}%
  \only<2>{\text{our destination}}%
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's so crazy but clever

Comment: @Themanofyourdream, I'm sure that there is more elegant solution.